# What is the best practice for determining when an animation has completed running?

Tags: c#, animation, unity-game-engine

Why doesn't this work?  I am finding that my while loop is exiting immediately.  My death animation takes about 1second, and I am watching the death state be active for that duration, after which, it exits to my Idle state.  Is there a timing issue, where my boolean condition is being tested before the death state is started?

I am trying to find a direct test on an animation for when it stops running.

```
private void playerDestroyed ()
{
    int deathHash = Animator.StringToHash("PlayerDeath");
    GameController.instance.pauseGame();
    _anim.Play(deathHash);
    while ( _anim.GetCurrentAnimatorStateInfo(0).nameHash == deathHash) {
        System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(100);
    }
    GameController.instance.gameOver();
}
```

**EDIT:**

So I changed my question to reflect what I'm really after: a best practice for knowing when an animation has completed.  I have seen examples using a WaitForSeconds strategy, but with the time to wait hardcoded, which is not ideal.  If I was to use this, I would want to pull the time of the animation, but I have had trouble accessing the animation clip length via the animator.

Comment: Does the animation begin playing immediately, or will the game wait one frame? This might be easier and safer to write as a [coroutine](http://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/Coroutines.html), rather than using thread sleeps (which would lock the game's main thread).

Comment: How do I know if it waits one frame?  Is this a setting?  I will write it as a coroutine (I actually thought my free version of Unity didn't allow coroutines, which is why I initially wrote it as above).  However, still struggling with what the test looks like.

Comment: So I figured out why the test was failing.  It seems that you must include the layer name as well.  You must hash "Base Layer.PlayerDeath" for it to work (for my case, since the animation is on the Base Layer).  This is a bit confusing that there would be 2 hashes that will successfully run the desired animation.  I hope that under the hood, Unity isn't reversing the hash, appending the layer name, and then rehashing to then be able to select the desired animation!

Answer (score 0):

Ok, kudos to rutter for mentioning the "will the game wait one frame".  It was driving me mental that the AnimationInfo[] coming back was null for me when I tried accessing the running clip.  I didn't think the Animator needed time to update it's statuses after a direct call to play an animation.

Also interestingly, I tried the same code but using a trigger instead of dealing with the hash business, and the code below fails.  My variable s comes back with Length of Zero.  The trigger needs more time than a single frame to work, I guess.

I thought I would put this together as an answer for how to achieve a test for an end of a clip.  However, please let me know if there is a better way!

```
    private void playerDestroyed ()
    {
        // a global var for the Animator object
        _anim = GetComponent<Animator>();  

        int hash = Animator.StringToHash("Base Layer.PlayerDeath");
        _anim.Play(deathHash);
        StartCoroutine("WaitForAnimation");
    }


    IEnumerator WaitForAnimation() {
        yield return new WaitForEndOfFrame();

        AnimationInfo[] s = _anim.GetCurrentAnimationClipState(0);
        yield return new WaitForSeconds( s[0].clip.length);

        //do something now, after the animation is complete
        GameOver();
    }
```

Comment: I tried this again today, and this code magically stopped working.  I guess it can take a few frames to get the animation running, and I can't guarantee it.  Is there a way to block my coroutine until the animation starts running?

Comment: Animation is playing while `normalizedTime < 1.0f`. This is the best way to detect it. When `normalizedTime < 1.0f` becomes `false` then animation is no longer playing. Also use `GetCurrentAnimatorStateInfo` instead which does not create garbage like `GetCurrentAnimationClipState`. Don't trust `clip.length` property with `WaitForSeconds`. That can be off sometimes.  See the duplicate complete solution for the `Animation` and `Animator` API.